# A method to create a set of folders based on strings in a text

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there a quick batch command that will let me select a text document and a directory and create a folder for each text string on a given line of the selected text document?

Comment: You will have to give examples of what you are creating and from which lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

cd /d "C:\output"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("c:\input\YourTextFile.txt") do (if not exist "%%a" md "%%a")
```

change paths as needed.